# Query working in Popsql, does not work in mysql.py. Python function works for other queries

Tags: python, sql, discord

I have a Python function that inserts a row for the command into the command_table.

```
def create_job_command(author:str):
    # command table has columns command_id(auto inc), command_author, client(bit), job(bit), job_num(bit), job_name and client_name
    insert_query = f'INSERT INTO command_table VALUES(NULL, "{author}", 1, 0, 0, "NULL", "NULL");'
    print(insert_query)
    print("create_job commmand")
    execute_query(connection, insert_query)
```

This works.

Then I have a function that makes it easy to update specific elements of the table.

```
def update_command_table(command_id, command_key:str, value):
    update_query = f"""
    UPDATE command_table 
    SET {command_key} = {value} 
    WHERE command_id = {command_id};
    """
    execute_query(connection, update_query)
```

This works for the first two calls to update_command_table but the third gives me an error:

```
        if command_dict['job_num'] == 1:
            drop_command(command_dict['command_id'])
            set_job_num(int(message.content))
        elif command_dict['client'] == 1:
            update_command_table(command_dict['command_id'], 'client', 0)
            update_command_table(command_dict['command_id'], 'job', 1)
            update_command_table(command_dict['command_id'], 'client_name', str(message.content))
```

The first two update_command_table functions change the value of the BIT at 'client' and 'job'.

The error I get is Error: '1054 (42S22): Unknown column '(user inputted string is message.content)' in 'field list''

I tried casting the message.content to string for whatever reason, and that didn't work.  I tried manually updating the "client_name" with a direct query from popsql and it updated it just fine.  I used the same SQL query from my python code and just changed the variables to what my program should have put in there.

Comment: The 3rd query works if I set the value its being changed to to an integer